# How to write MySQL multilines condition with RubyOnRails?

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, conditional-statements, quote

I want to use the "?" char for a search in a MySQL request in rails.
For example, classical way is:

```
Model.where("name = ?", '#{@search}')
```

My question is about long queries and multilines condition.
If I want to build a condition manually:

```
where = ""
where << " status = 1 "
where << " AND MATCH (name) AGAINST (? IN BOOLEAN MODE), @search " if @search
@records = Model.where(where)
```

Of course, it won't work.
So how to use the "?" (for security and simplicity) with a multilines conditions ?

A simple way is to do that:

```
where << " MATCH (name) AGAINST ('#{@search}' IN BOOLEAN MODE) "
```

But I will lose security (SQL injection) and can have problems with quotes if @search contains quotes.

Thanks,

Comment: _can have problems with quotes_ - where is problems? [Have you read the Rails documentation?](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/security.html#sql-injection)

Comment: The problem is if I search for something like that "bouquet d'alexander", the sql query generates an error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're getting a bit confused about the contents of where: you're putting variable names inside the string, which won't work: "@search" inside a string becomes literally the word "@search" and not a variable.

The best way to think of the arguments to `where` is as an array of objects, and you can build it like this. The first object is the query string (with ? symbols) and the other elements are the values for the ? symbols, which will be sanitized and translated by rails.

eg

```
User.where(["first_name = ? and last_name = ?", "John", "Smith"])
```

you can pass other things to where, like a hash of values, or a single string, but the array is the most flexible, especially in your case.

Bearing that in mind, you can do something like this to build a dynamically-created, complex query: i use this pattern a lot as it's very flexible and also very readable.

```
condition_strings = []
condition_values = []

condition_strings << "status = ?"
condition_values << 1 #or some dynamic data

condition_strings << "MATCH (name) AGAINST (? IN BOOLEAN MODE)"
condition_values << @search

conditions = [condition_strings.join(" AND ")] + condition_values
# => ["status = ? AND MATCH (name) AGAINST (? IN BOOLEAN MODE)", 1, "foo"]

#now we can use the array as an argument to `.where`:
@records = Model.where(conditions)
```

Comment: I have quite the same issue with a "select" : `Model.select('articles.*, MATCH (name) AGAINST ("' + @search + '" IN BOOLEAN MODE) AS pertinence').where(where)` As you can see, I need a custom "select" and suppose I can't use the ? symbol in a select. What is my alternative to use Rails sanitization ?

Comment: Put it in the ".where" instead of in a ".select".  But, more generally, you should make your own question for this.

Comment: I need to put it in the select because I need the "AS pertinence" field to classify results. I will open a new question.